# If $P(X_1 < X_2)$, what is $P(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_1 < X_3)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say $X_i$ can have a real value in the range [1,100]. All $X_i$ are independent of each other and all values are equally likely.

So then $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2) = \frac{1}{2}$, right?

But then, what is $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_1 < X_3)$?

Hints would be greatly welcome.

**Edit:**

So $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_1 < X_3) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X_2)$

Now all I have to do is find $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X_2)$...

Comment: How are the $X_i$ distributed?  Are they all uniform?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the distribution.

Comment: Hint: Can you compare $P(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_1 < X_3)$, $P(X_2 < X_1 \cap X_2 < X_3)$ and $P(X_3 < X_1 \cap X_3 < X_2)$? What is their sum? (Note that this is reminiscent of the case of two random variables, which can be solved by comparing $P(X_1 < X_2)$ and $P(X_2 < X_1)$ and computing their sum.)

Comment: I'm guessing 1?

Comment: $P(X_1<X_2) = 1/2$ is true. Intuitively, for the other case, we have that $P(X_1< \min\{X_2,X_3\}) = \frac{1!2!}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: Is this right? Since  $P(X1<X2∩X1<X3), P(X2<X1∩X2<X3)$ and $P(X3<X1∩X3<X2)$ equally partition the sample space, the answer is $1/3$?

Comment: @probablyme could you please explain $P(X_1 < min\{X_2,X_3\})= \frac{1!2!}{3!}$?

Comment: You just need to order them. We have one choice for the first (it has to be $X_1$) and we have two choices for remaining (either $X_2$ or $X_3$ is smaller). Finally all possibly was to order the three is $3!$.

Comment: This is only true since they are iid continuous.